# Azure Auto Scaling

Tags: azure

Is there an equivalent functionality in Azure like AWS Auto Scaling Group or GCP Instance Group? All I can find is Azure Virtual Machine Scale Set which always uses load balancer. The closest resource I found is Azure Automation Runbook which a bit more complex for my use case.

I just need to spin up virtual machines based on current vm's health threshold and/or to use it for vertical scaling by simply change the instance type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an Azure VMSS without a loadbalancer, you *may* need to assign a pubic IP addresses to your VM which is now available.  In your case it sounds like you just want 1 node in the VMSS so you can use **AutoScale**.

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-networking#public-ipv4-per-virtual-machine

Comment: Thanks a lot Ken, this is exactly what I needed! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent Azure service for AWS Auto Scaling Group or GCP Instance Group is **Azure Autoscale**.

I'll provide some basic overview on Azure's Autoscale taken from [here](https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/best-practices-auto-scaling.md).

> Azure Autoscale supports the most common scaling scenarios based on a
>   schedule and, optionally, triggered scaling operations based on
>   runtime metrics (such as processor utilization, queue length, or
>   built-in and custom counters). 
>  You can configure simple autoscaling
>   policies for a solution quickly and easily by using the Azure portal.
>   For more detailed control, you can make use of the Azure Service
>   Management REST API or the Azure Resource Manager REST API.  
> The Azure
>   Monitoring Service Management Library and the Microsoft Insights
>   Library (in preview) are SDKs that allow collecting metrics from
>   different resources, and perform autoscaling by making use of the REST
>   APIs.  
> For resources where Azure Resource Manager support isn't
>   available, or if you are using Azure Cloud Services, the Service
>   Management REST API can be used for autoscaling. In all other cases,
>   use Azure Resource Manager.

**The mentioned article is a great resource.**

It also provides information about:

1. [Types of scaling](https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/best-practices-auto-scaling.md#types-of-scaling) (Vertical Vs Horizontal).
2. [Configure autoscaling for an Azure solution](https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/best-practices-auto-scaling.md#configure-autoscaling-for-an-azure-solution).
3. [How to use Azure Autoscale](https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/best-practices-auto-scaling.md#use-azure-autoscale).
4. [Application design considerations for implementing autoscaling](https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/best-practices-auto-scaling.md#application-design-considerations-for-implementing-autoscaling).

Check out also [this](https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/cloud-services/cloud-services-how-to-scale.md) resource on *How to auto scale a cloud service*.